# Why does the last frame show up before first in animation?

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I was trying to make a "bounce-in" effect where the circle isn't there before the animation, then the animation is executed on scroll, and the circle remains there after the animation is over. But for some reason it's there even before the animation, then disappears (since first frame opacity is 0) then appears again. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```js
if (browser.canUse('transition')) {

  var on = function() {

      // Circles

      $('.circle')
        .scrollex({
          mode: 'bottom',
          delay: 50,
          initialize: function() {
            $(this).addClass('bounceIn');
          },
          terminate: function() {
            $(this).removeClass('bounceIn');
          },
          enter: function() {
            $(this).removeClass('bounceIn');
          },
          leave: function() {
            $(this).addClass('bounceIn');
          }
        });
```

```css
.circle {
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.circle.circle1 {
  top: 80px;
  left: 120px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: white;
  opacity: 0;
}


/* ----------- BOUNCE IN ------------*/

@-webkit-keyframes bounceIn {
  from,
  20%,
  40%,
  60%,
  80%,
  to {
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.315, 0.71, 0.455, 1);
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.315, 0.71, 0.455, 1);
  }
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.3);
    transform: scale(0.3);
  }
  20% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.03);
    transform: scale(1.03);
  }
  40% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.9);
    transform: scale(0.9);
  }
  60% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.03);
    transform: scale(1.03);
  }
  80% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.97);
    transform: scale(0.97);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

@keyframes bounceIn {
  from,
  20%,
  40%,
  60%,
  80%,
  to {
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.315, 0.71, 0.455, 1);
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.315, 0.71, 0.455, 1);
  }
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.3);
    transform: scale(0.3);
  }
  20% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.03);
    transform: scale(1.03);
  }
  40% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.9);
    transform: scale(0.9);
  }
  60% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.03);
    transform: scale(1.03);
  }
  80% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.97);
    transform: scale(0.97);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

.bounceIn {
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-name: bounceIn;
  animation-name: bounceIn;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle circle1"></div>
```

Comment: I didn't post the entire js code, so probably just didn't copy it

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]?